# Automatically copy rows to a new sheet when a cell is is changed excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I know this has been posted as a question numerous times. But I just can't get it working, I've tried numerous methods.

I have `code` that auto copies specific `rows` to a new `sheet` when a specific `value` is entered into `Column B`. But this only occurs when assign the marco to a button and manually trigger it. This isn't very efficient when copying over numerous rows. Especially when you're copying over hundreds of rows with only the last few actually changing. I'm hoping this will automatically happen when that value is entered.

So my `first` `sheet` is called `MASTER` and the `second` `sheet` is called `CON`. When `Change of Numbers` is entered into the `MASTER` I want to automatically copy these `rows` into sheet `CON`.

This `code` below is situated in The `Master` `Sheet` (which is the first). This `script` is used to hide/unhide specific `Columns` when values are entered into `Column B`.

**MASTER SHEET**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "Change of Numbers"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("H:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The following `script` is situated in `sheet` `CON` (which is the second sheet). This `script` is used to `auto-copy` the `rows` where `X` is entered into `Column A` in the `Master sheet`. However I have to assign this macro to a button on this sheet. It then grabs all the designated rows each time the macro is triggered.

**CON SHEET**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("MASTER")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("CON")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Change of Numbers"

        .Range("A:F, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(2, "B")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .Range("H:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
    End With
End Sub
```

But this still doesn't work without manually running the script.

Comment: Would calling your first sub be sufficient? If so, in the `Worksheet_Change`, just swap the `MsgBox` line with `FilterandCopy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not watching for any events to take place. The particular event you want is the `Worksheet_Change()` event, which is what I see in the second code snippet you provided.

So, you can go about this two ways. One, copy and paste the entire code into this event, or two (which is usually preferred) would be to call the sub within the event handler.

However, for the *Worksheet* to watch for the *Change Event*, you need to place this into the worksheet's code module. In the VBE, you will see this as `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc.

My recommendation, place your `Sub FilterAndCopy()` in a standard module. Then **in `Sheet1`'s code module**, add:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Test if criteria is met
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Value = "mySpecificValue" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        FilterAndCopy

        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("a:a"))
            Select Case UCase(t.Value)
                Case "X"
                    Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Case "Y"
                    Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t

    End If

ErrHandler:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Rem: Optional - Error message and/or err recovery
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code but it's returning an error. Does the code in master (first sheet) affect your code?

Comment: You can only have **one** `Worksheet_Change()` event in the worksheet's code module. What error are you receiving?

Comment: Error: Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet Change. That initial code in the master hides/unhides columns in that sheet.

Comment: Yes, so you can only have one `Worksheet_Change()`. You can just move that code to another sub like you have done with `FilterAndCopy`. Then call both subs in the one `Worksheet_Change()` event. You can only have one in each module.

Comment: But what do I call the sub if it's not Worksheet Change. If I call it FilterAndCopy it doesn't work

Comment: I updated my code @JPA0888. Remember, you can only have 1 single `Worksheet_Change()` event in a module. So, it's going to run the `FilterAndCopy` code first, then the other loop you have. If you need it to run after, then simply move the line below the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you first sub works exactly as intended all you need to do is `Call` the sub from your `Worksheet_Change` event. Just to be clear, as your `Worksheet_Change` macro is set-up, it will only call if the change is made on `Column A`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
    On Error GoTo Finalize 'to re-enable the events
        FilterAndCopy

Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code only works when I run the Marco or assign it to a button. This isn't ideal when I'm filtering and copying over thousands of rows each time. Is there a way it automatically copies without being prompted?

Comment: This should be pasted on the sheet with the change to trigger macro

Comment: I can't have two Worksheet_Changes though?

Comment: Using the code in the question. I can't copy your solution into the MASTER sheet

Comment: The other sub wouldn’t be a work sheet change. Just a good ol fashion Sub FilterandCopy ()

Comment: So on the CON sheet?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following at all. Which sheet and what part should your code be copied into?

Comment: If I change the current MASTER sheet code to a filter it won't hide/unhide columns

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate your code into the script I've labelled in the question. I'm finding it difficult to get the sequence right